# Large space between LI when only two boxes shown - why?

Tags: html, css

I have been developing a small template, this is the entry from my CSS causing problems:

```css
body {
  background-color: #D6ECEF;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header.commerce1 {
  background-color: #D2691E;
  color: #FFFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 22px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.content {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 860px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul.stock {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul.stock li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 88%;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #FFF;
  column-gap: 3px;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-height: auto;
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul.stock li h3 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}


/* 

ul.dealers li h3 {
color: red;
}
*/

ul.stock li p {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  width: 230px;
  white-space: initial;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

ul.stock li img {
  height: 180px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #a2a9b1;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0.2em 0
}

p {
  margin: 0.4em 0 0.5em 0
}

p img {
  margin: 0
}

ul {
  margin: 0.3em 0 0 1.6em;
  padding: 0
}

ol {
  margin: 0.3em 0 0 3.2em;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-image: none
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 0.1em
}

dt {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em
}

dl {
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em
}

dd {
  margin-left: 1.6em;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em
}

h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 30px 0 0
}

h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative
}


/* 
h2 {
font-size:18pt;
line-height:24pt;
margin-bottom:0.25em
}
h3 {
font-size:14pt;
line-height:20pt
}
h4,
h5,
h6 {
font-size:12pt;
line-height:16pt
}
*/

h2 {
  line-height: 24pt;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

h3 {
  line-height: 20pt;
}

h4,
h5,
h6 {
  line-height: 16pt;
}

ol,
ul {
  margin: 10px 0 0 1.6em;
  padding: 0
}

ol li,
ul li {
  padding: 2px 0;
  font-size: 12pt
}

q {
  quotes: '"' '"' "'" "'"
}

blockquote {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0 40px
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

hr.archive-aex {
  border: 5px dotted #ff0000;
  border-style: none none dotted;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#content {}

[id="Content"] {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.mw-body {
  padding: 1.25em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
}

.mw-body {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border: 1px solid #a7d7f9;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

[id="bodyContent"] p,
.vector-body p {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

[id="bodyContent"],
.vector-body {
  font-size: calc(1em * 0.875);
  line-height: 1.6;
}

div.stockimg img {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<header class="commerce1">
  <h2>MY AUCTION SITE TEMPLATE</h2>
</header>
<div class="content">
  <h3>T-SHIRTS SALE</h3>
  <ul class="stock">
    <li>
      <div class="stockimg">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/LIOR_FOR_ATHENA.JPG">
        <p><b>Women's T-shirt</b>, white <b>WAS £10.00 NOW £5.00</b>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="stockimg">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/11_p_edit_edit.jpg/800px-11_p_edit_edit.jpg">
      </div>
      <p><b>Men's blue T-shirt</b>, Size M <b>WAS £8.00 NOW £5.00</b>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Image from development site:

[image: Image from site]

If the ul class stock has three items in the list, the space isn't huge, but if there's only two it's huge.

I've been trying to experiment with margins and it's still got quite a large gap in between if there's two rows.

How could I fix the margin so that if there's just two items in a list it's not a huge gap, currently I've been trying to fix gap, columns etc.?

Comment: Because of `justify-content: space-between;` in the CSS for `ul.stock`, I believe.

Comment: If you don't want the remaining space to be inserted between items (which `justify-content: space-between;` does), how would you want the last row to look like?

Comment: @Terry: It's about space between the li elements.

Comment: @avenas8808 That doesn't answer my question. If you don't want to space to be inserted between items, then how are you going to layout 5 items in a 3x2 grid? How should the last row look like?

Comment: @Terry: Figured it out, I used justify-content: space-between when gap would have worked better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to your [flex justification](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-justify-content) being `space-between`, which distributes an even amount of space between items. This is why two listings results in a larger gap than three.

Try using `justify-content: flex-start` on your `ul` and adding a the value you'd like to be your margin as a gap (for example, `gap: 1rem`).

Comment: Thank you. I've done what you said and that works much better. I've made this the accepted answer.

Comment: No problem @avenas8808!